# I can't update software using yum on CentOS

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

When I use the command `yum update` to update the software on CentOS, it gives the following error and not sure how to fix it:

```
 Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.4-el5.centos is needed by package php-mhash
 Error: Missing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12) is needed by package libcurl
 Error: Missing Dependency: libnssutil3.so is needed by package libcurl
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
yum install php-common libnss3.so libnssutil3.so
yum update
```

EDIT:
Execute them as root

```
sudo yum install php-common libnss3.so libnssutil3.so
sudo yum update
```